# Asymptotics of $\sum_{k=1}^nd(k^s)$, the sum of the divisor counts of the squares, cubes, etc.

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, divisor-counting-function

Let $d(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n$. It is well known that $$\sum_{k=1}^nd(k)=\sum_{d=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor=\Theta(n\log n).$$ Purely based on experimentation, I expect for integral $s\geq1$, in general, we get $$\sum_{k=1}^nd(k^s)=\Theta(n\log^sn),$$ but I see no way of proving or disproving this claim, not even for $s=2$. Are there any known results on the asymptotics of $\sum_{k=1}^nd(k^s)$?

Comment: do u have either bound (upper or lower)?

Comment: @mathworker21 Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do $s=2$. The higher values of $s$ should be able to be handled similarly.

$\sum_{k \le n} \tau(k^2) = \sum_{k \le n} \sum_{d \mid k^2} 1 = \sum_{d \le n^2} \sum_{\substack{k \le n \\ d \mid k^2}} 1$. This motivates us to write $d=a^2b$ with $b$ square-free. In the following, $b$ is always square-free. $\sum_{a^2b \le n} \sum_{\substack{k \le n \\ a^2b \mid k^2}} 1 = \sum_{a^2b \le n^2} \sum_{\substack{k \le n \\ ab \mid k}} 1 = \sum_{a^2b \le n^2} \lfloor \frac{n}{ab}\rfloor = \sum_{\substack{a^2b \le n^2 \\ ab \le n}} \lfloor \frac{n}{ab}\rfloor$ and since $ab \le n$ implies $a^2b \le n^2$, we get $= \sum_{ab \le n} \left[\frac{n}{ab}+O(1)\right] = \sum_{b \le n} \sum_{a \le \frac{n}{b}} \left[\frac{n}{ab}+O(1)\right] = \sum_{b \le n} \left[\frac{n}{b}\log(\frac{n}{b})+O(\frac{n}{b})\right]$. Recall the sum is over square-free $b$. However, square-free integers are just $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ density of integers and are uniformly distributed enough, so since you just want a $\Theta$ bound, we can just pretend the (purely analytic and not arithemtic) sum is over all $b \le n$. Then we get $\Theta(n\log^2 n)$, as desired.

Comment: Very nice, I like the $d=a^2b$ step. I think to generalize this, you can write $d=a^s\cdot b_{s-1}^{s-1}b_{s-2}^{s-2}...b_1$ with all $b_i$ pairwise co-prime and square-free. Happy holidays to you too :)

Comment: @SmileyCraft people keep deleting my comments; im getting kinda annoyed. anyways, I'm not actually sure how to generalize after thinking about it, but maybe what you said works. If you decide to work it out and run into trouble, lemme know. happy holidays

Comment: @SmileyCraft I think the argument gives $\sim$, not just $\Theta$.

Comment: Well there has to be a constant, right? For $s=2$ we already had $6/\pi^2$. If $\rho$ is the density of coprime $s-1$-tuples of squarefree integers in $\mathbb{N}^{s-1}$, then there will be a constant factor of $\rho$. I'm not sure if there is an easy formula for this, or even what this constant is for $s=3$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft (1) I don't see why there has to be a constant (2) even if there had to be a constant, my previous comment was making the stronger claim that the argument provided in the answer yields the constant. (3) I agree with the third sentence of your comment (counting the question as a sentence).

Comment: I've worked out $s=2$, and from $$\int_1^n\frac{n}{x}\log\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)\ \mbox{d}x=\frac12n\log^2n$$ we get another factor $\frac12$. So we get $\sum_{k\leq n}d(k^2)\sim\frac3{\pi^2}n\log^2n$. For $n=10^7$, I get $974287906\sim789676050$, so this ratio converges quite slowly, it appears. I believe this comes from the $\Theta(n\log n)$ error term.

Comment: @SmileyCraft that's strange. we could do $\sum_{ab \le n} \lfloor \frac{n}{ab} \rfloor \le \sum_{ab \le n} \frac{n}{ab} = \sum_{b \le n} \frac{n}{b}[\log(n/b)+\gamma+O(\frac{b}{n})] = \sum_{b \le n} \frac{n}{b}\log(\frac{n}{b})+\gamma n\log n+O(n)$, and we're off by a lot (assuming implicit constant in big $O$ is reasonable small, which I think it is), in that 974287906 is decently larger, though maybe I'm worrying too much.

Comment: @SmileyCraft actually yea, I think the discrepancy comes from the fact that it's easier for a number to be square-free earlier on, i.e., the density of square-free numbers is initially much larger than $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ (which can be intuited from the fact that the $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ is obtained from multiplying $(1-\frac{1}{p^2})$ over *all* primes $p$, which is of course really unnecessary for small values of $n$). [Also, in my previous comment, it should have been $\frac{6}{\pi^2}\gamma n\log n$ instead of $\gamma n\log n$ at the end. This makes the (now explained) "strangeness" stronger.]